# Heapsort Algorithm by Cormen Implementation in C , not working correctly

Tags: c, algorithm, heapsort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXSIZE    100
#define LEFT(X)    (2*(X))
#define RIGHT(X)   ((2*(X)) + 1)
#define Parent(X)  ((X)/2)

void inputElements(int *arr ,int *size);
void printElements(int *arr , int size);
void max_heapify(int *arr , int index , int heap_size);
void build_max_heap(int *arr,int heap_size);
void heap_sort(int *arr , int heap_size);

int main(){

    int arr[MAXSIZE] ;
    int size = 0;

    inputElements(arr , &size);
    printElements(arr , size);

    heap_sort(arr, size);
    printf("Array after Heap Sort");
    printElements(arr , size);


    return 0 ;
}


void inputElements(int *arr ,int *size){


    printf("Enter Size of Array(max %d)..\n" , MAXSIZE);
    scanf("%d",size);

    printf("Enter the array Elements..\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<(*size) ; i++){
        scanf("%d" , (arr+i));
    }

}

void printElements(int *arr , int size){

    printf("Printing Array Elements..\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
        printf("%d\n" , arr[i]);
    }

}


void build_max_heap(int *arr,int heap_size){

    for(int i=((heap_size)/2) ; i>=0 ; i--){

        max_heapify(arr , i , heap_size);
    }

}

void max_heapify(int *arr , int index , int heap_size){

    int l ,r , largest , temp;

    l = LEFT(index);
    r = RIGHT(index);

    if ((l < heap_size) && (arr[l] > arr[index])) {
        largest = l;
    } else {
        largest = index;
    }

    if ((r < heap_size) && (arr[r] > arr[index])) {
        largest = r;
    }

    if (largest != index) {
        temp = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[largest];
        arr[largest] = temp;
        max_heapify(arr , largest , heap_size);
    }

}



void heap_sort(int *arr , int heap_size){

    int temp = -1 , i ;
    build_max_heap(arr,heap_size);

    for (i = (heap_size-1); i >= 1; i--) {

        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[0];
        arr[0] = temp;
        heap_size = heap_size-1;
        max_heapify(arr , 0 , heap_size);
    }

}
```

The main function first asks for the size of the array, then the numbers to be sorted are stored in the array.
The heap_sort function first calls the build_max_heap to convert the array into a heap, sorts the array.

When I am running the algorithm on a set of numbers say :
90
45
33
22
66
4

The Output after running the algorithm isL
4
45
22
33
66
90

Not able to track where the indexes are going wrong.

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger and stepped through the code line by line?

Comment: I believe your Left and right functions may have an off by one error. Left(0) should not be 0 (it should be 1), Right(0) should not be 1 (it should be 2). Left of 1 should not be 2 (it should be 3), right of 1 should not be 3 (it should be 4), ect

Comment: I fixed the LEFT and RIGHT macros, and the implementation is working coreectly now. Thanks@IdeaHat

Comment: Your original LEFT and RIGHT are for 1-based arrays.  In algorithms, details matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your Left and right functions may have an off by one error. Left(0) should not be 0 (it should be 1), Right(0) should not be 1 (it should be 2). Left of 1 should not be 2 (it should be 3), right of 1 should not be 3 (it should be 4), ect – IdeaHat